# Combine multiple array to object collection using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have some information collected by array, like:

```
var names = ["Jack", "Marry", "Bob"]
var cars = ["Audi", "BMW", "Volvo"]
```

I want these info combine to object like collection, like:

```
[{name:"Jack", car: "Audi"}, {name: "Marry", car:"BMW"}, {name:"Bob", car:"Volvo"}]
```

I can do this by some steps:

```
var combine = _.zip(names, cars)
var collection= _.map(combine, function(info){
                      return _.object(["name", "car"], info);
                     });
```

Is there other way to make code look better?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with Underscore, you could combine your two steps using [chaining](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining):

```
var result = _(names).chain()
                     .zip(cars)
                     .map(function(a) { return { name: a[0], car: a[1] } })
                     .value();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about es5 [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

```
var names = ["Jack", "Marry", "Bob"]
var cars = ["Audi", "BMW", "Volvo"]

var result = names.map(function(val, key){
 return {name: val, car: cars[key]}
})

console.log(result); //[{car: "Audi", name: "Jack"}, {car: "BMW", name: "Marry"}, {car: "Volvo", name: "Bob"}]
```

P.S. please add a condition for case if arrays will have different length